# How to start a service even if user force close it?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

i want to start my service even if user force stop the app or some other app force stop my app.
Here is my code.

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopLocationUpdates();

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: start your service again in `onDestroy()`  method.

Comment: Why do want to do this? As a user, I'd uninstall immediately. If I force stop, I **want** it stopped. I'd consider auto-restart after force stop (possibly) harmful.

Comment: check your service is running or not in your splash screen and then restart your service if its stooped .

Comment: @Fildor actually other apps stop my app like ShuttApp Force stop my app

Comment: Yeah, so? Do they have a reason to do so? I guess if they do it once, they will do it repeatedly ... wouldn't it make more sense to stop them from stopping the App?

Comment: @Chetan i check the service current state by using this code
private static boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your time can you guide me more ,Actually i am newbie and want to update my location on server after every 10 minute interval but other apps kill my service what should i do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "actually other apps stop my app like ShuttApp Force stop my app" -- no, they do not, except perhaps on a rooted device. "Force Stop" has a *very* specific meaning, tied to the behavior of the "Force Stop" button in Settings. Ordinary apps do not have the ability to "Force Stop" other apps.

Comment: Well, if your bucket has a hole, there's no sense in just always refill it with water. You gotta fix the hole. In your case: Find out what causes apps like ShuttApp to force close your App. Then you can think about counter-measures.

Comment: "ShutApp does not mean to interrupt all background apps but for the ones that do not need to be working in the background, ShutApp can help you shut down them to avoid consuming more battery or network data." - So I guess they'll have some sort of "Exceptions" - Config for Apps that shall not be closed. If it cannot be configured to leave your app alone, I'd publish that your app is incompatible with using battery savers ...

Comment: Thanks All of you now i got the exact point

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it is really very bad pattern to run service forcefully against 
    the user's willingness.
    Anyways, you can restart it by using a BroadcastReceiver which handles the 
    broadcast sent from onDestroy() of your service.

StickyService.java

```
public class StickyService extends Service
 {
private static final String TAG = "StickyService";


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("YouWillNeverKillMe"));
}

}
```

RestartServiceReceiver.java

```
public class RestartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

private static final String TAG = "RestartServiceReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");
context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), 
StickyService.class));

}

  }
```

Declare the components in manifest file

```
 <service android:name=".StickyService" >
</service>

<receiver android:name=".RestartServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="YouWillNeverKillMe" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Start the StickyService in a Component (i.e. Application, Activity, Fragment):
`startService(new Intent(this, StickyService.class));`

Answer (score -1):

I start service in `onDestroy()`.This code will work for me if any one have more efficient way to do this please comment on it.

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    startLocationUpdateService(); 
    }
```